# pygame position error

Tags: pygame

First of all ,I loaded a picture of the ship and initialized its location. thereafter I add bullet to my program. After that, I found that no matter how I debug it, it can't be in the right place.

```
# 1. - import library
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Player(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('image/pig.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()


class Bullet(Sprite):          
    def __init__(self, player):
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, bullet_width, bullet_height )
        self.color = bullet_color
        self.rect.center = player.rect.center 
        self.rect.left  = player.rect.right

# 2. - Initialize the game 
pygame.init()
width,height = 800,600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
keys = [False,False,False,False]
playerpos = [0,288] 
bullet_width = 15
bullet_height = 6
bullet_color  = (200, 200 , 0)

player = Player()
bullet = Bullet(player)

grass = pygame.image.load("image/bg.bmp")

# 4. - keep looping through
while True:
    # 5. - clear the screen before drawing it again.
    screen.fill(0) 
    # 6. - Draw the screen elements.
    screen.blit(grass,(0,0))
    screen.blit(player.image, playerpos)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, bullet.color, bullet.rect)
    # 7. - update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    # 8. - loop through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check if the event is the X button.
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:   
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

and why bullet appear in top-left
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o83Bc.png)

*I hope bullet appear in ship's right side,but I can't do it if I don't use coordinate（x，y），how can I do it?*

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing the ship in a position unrelated to its rect's position, using playerpos. You need to make the link the ship's position linked to its rect, so that the bullet can access it:

```
# 1. - import library
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Player(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('image/pig.bmp')
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()


class Bullet(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, player):
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, bullet_width, bullet_height )
        self.color = bullet_color
        self.rect.center = player.rect.center
        self.rect.left  = player.rect.right

# 2. - Initialize the game
pygame.init()
width,height = 800,600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
keys = [False,False,False,False]

bullet_width = 15
bullet_height = 6
bullet_color  = (200, 200 , 0)

player = Player()
player.rect.topleft = [0,288]
bullet = Bullet(player)

grass = pygame.image.load("image/bg.bmp")

# 4. - keep looping through
while True:
    # 5. - clear the screen before drawing it again.
    screen.blit(grass, (0, 0))
    # 6. - Draw the screen elements.
    screen.blit(player.image, player.rect.topleft)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, bullet.color, bullet.rect)
    # 7. - update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    # 8. - loop through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check if the event is the X button.
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

This is because a surface's `get_rect()` method has no idea where the surface is going to be blitted on to another surface, so it just gives its position as (0, 0). `get_rect()` is only useful for obtaining a surface's dimensions.